# Ubuntu 14.04 apt-get fails on Google Chrome

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, software-sources

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new hard drive. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `sources.list` file, indeed, makes no mention of any "binary-i386". Should I manually add that line to the file?